# PIC to PC via USART or USB

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, usart, hyperterminal

I was introduced to the PIC some 15yrs ago, and haven't really touched it since. I now want to start a project requiring (I think) a PIC, but all my software/hardware seems antiquated and/or obsolete. I've upgraded the early PIC16F877 to a PIC16F18877 and am currently waiting for my ICD3 to arrive, I'm hopeing I can still use my Dev board (ICD Demo Board rev1 by Advanced Transdata Co).

I've downloaded and aquainted myself with the MPLAB X IDE and associated 'C' compiler, however when I was messing with PIC's, one of the options for output testing etc was through the RS232 to a hyperterminal on the PC.

However, the ICD3 is connected by USB, and although the old Dev Board has an RS232 'D' type socket, the PC (Win7) has no Hyperterminal software or COM sockets. Digging around on here I think I need to use a USB 2.0 to TTL UART 6PIN CP2102 Module Serial Converter from the Dev board to the PC's USB sockets but how can I see the output on screen, or should I be using some other method?

Regards

Les

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.

Comment: How is it off topic, there's no topic category. The page just says post a question. So I have, if you don't have an answer thats fine.

Comment: @Rob this is definitely stackoverflow worthy.

Comment: @JayC In what way, shape or form is this a programming question?

Comment: @Rob in what way, shape, or form is this not stackoverflow worthy?  I didn't say it was a programming question. Any question meeting the stackoverflow guidelines relating to HTML or cascading style sheets (without the use of javascript) is not direct programming question, either, but it would be stackoverflow worthy.

Comment: @JayC This is a hardware question, not software related (or actually, how do I get my hardware to work). You need to read [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Rob https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic => This fits under a "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".  Developing microcontroller code is a type of software development.  This question is specific to testing or debugging a microcontroller through the use of some interface to a PC.  If you want to argue there's a better StackExchange option, that's fine, but rather than saying the question is off-topic, it would be better to point to where the question is on topic.  As far as I can tell, though, this is not off-topic.

Comment: @Rob, this is not a "how do I get my hardware to work" question.  It is not that generic.  It is answerable, with a few possible solutions.

Comment: Many thanks guys, I ordered (and received) a USB to Serial cable, as suggested and installed drivers, ICD3 turned up (finally), first simple test program uploaded and running :D, now to crack on with confirming terminal connection is working. Thanks again for your assistance peeps :thumbup

Answer (score 1):

On a machine with no COM ports, you must use a USB-RS232 converter.  This will create a virtual COM port when plugged in.

For a serial terminal on Windows 7 or later, if you have access to a Windows XP machine, simply copying over the HyperTerminal executable will work in windows 7.  The program remains compatible, they just stopped including it in Windows (since COM ports are quite rare on modern PCs and getting rarer).

You could also use a serial terminal program such as PuTTY, or an alternative like AccessPort (which I like because I can easily send/receive hex bytes with it).

Answer (score 0):

I can make your life easier... Most people who use pic devices use a PicKit3 (very inexpensive), with that tool and Microchip's MPLAB X, you can do all the debugging you need.  The IDE has a built-in simulator, so you can experiment with your code prior to getting your hardware setup.  Once you get your hardware and a PicKit3, you simply connect the PicKit to your computer via USB and to your micro via the 5 pin (says 6 but the 6th is unused) connector and you can now single step, step over, step into, set breakpoints and so on.
I've used the older serial based ICD, and by far, the new method/tools is amazing, especially given the low cost of the PicKit3
Enjoy and welcome back to programming

Comment: Thanks!  Apparently it was not appreciated by all.  Hopefully the person who demoted it will fix that

Answer (score 0):

K_Trenholm GDC is right. Download Terminal tool for xp it will work on 7, or download realterm from Bell labs it will also work on 7.
For communication there are two methods:

1- MCU_UART(TTL-Logic) to RS-232 (PC, if have com port), this will require in middle some logic converter like max232 to map levels of TTL to RS-232.

2- Use Prolific pl2303 or Silicon Labs cp2102 modules. You won need logic converters and you don't need com ports on PC.

Connect usb to PC, install driver for module (easily available from company sites), it will create a virtual com port and connect that port into Terminal or other tool.
Hope this helps..